# Constructing a topology of $\Bbb Z$ whose complement is also infinite. $A$ is open, singletons are not open and the topology is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

Fix an infinite subset $A\subset\Bbb Z$ whose complement $Z\setminus A$ is also infinite.  Construct a topology on $\Bbb Z$ in which:

**(a)** $A$ is open.

**(b)**  Singletons are never open (i.e.,  $\forall n\in\Bbb Z,\{n\}$ is not open).

**(c)**  For any pair of distinct integers $m$ and $n$, there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ s. t. $m\in U\;\land\;n\in V$.

I don't know how to proceed.  I considered having $A$ being positive integers, or even integers or prime integers...but don't know how to proceed further.  Without providing a solution, what are some hints I can use to construct such a topology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very slick way is to let $f:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Q$ be a bijection, set $A=f^{-1}[(0,1)]$, and let the topology on $\Bbb Z$ be

$$\tau=\{f^{-1}[U]:U\text{ is open in the usual topology on }\Bbb Q\}\;.$$

(The usual topology on $\Bbb Q$ is the one that it inherits as a subspace of $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology.) I leave it to you to verify that this works.